# Can I combine multiple transactions from same users?

Tags: contract-development, transactions

If I send 10 transactions from user A to B within let's say an hour, is it possible to combine these transactions into one to save on transaction fees?

It's important these transactions are still viewable by putting the transaction codes or hash in the metadata or some other place.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pay once and have multiple transactions in a way that will list them on a site like Etherscan, but you can combine the payments using payment channels. Raiden is probably the most known implementations of payment channels on Ethereum, but it's not released yet and there isn't a release date yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, transactions are not adjustable or killed or combined.